# Redirect www ssl to non-www ssl nginx

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

I'm redirecting http traffic to https with an nginx reverse proxy, but when I try to redirect "www" https traffic, the browser throws a security error because our certificate is for the non-www version.

I've been trying to find a way to redirect without triggering the security error, but am having no luck.

Here's an example redirect of our http->https traffic.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Here's a non-working block for redirecting www https:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl on;
    // ssl key/crt etc here
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

SSL at first process handshake and only after handshake it sends request.

You can not redirect during handshake, so it is impossible. You need a proper certificate